# Reactive Form - A control is invalid but form is still valid

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Consider this code :

```
foo(){
...
    aControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
          if (value == AmountType.FIXED) {
            variableAmount.setValidators(null);
            variableAmount.setValue(null);
            fixedAmount.setValidators(Validators.required);
          }
          else{
            fixedAmount.setValidators(null);
            fixedAmount.setValue(null);
            variableAmount.setValidators(Validators.required);
            console.log(form.valid)
            console.log(form.get('variableAmount').valid)
          }
}
```

"true" then "false" get printed in the console. 
How can such a situation happen? How can a form be valid while one of its controls isn't?

I tried form.updateValueAndValidity() and form.get('variableAmount').updateValueAndValidity() but nothing changes.

Comment: implement custom validators

Comment: How could a custom validator help me? My problem is that my form validity does't reflect its real state...

Comment: try use UpdateValueAndValidity https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updatevalueandvalidity after setValidator

Comment: I already tried... Before and after setValidators() but no impact

Comment: My control called variableAmount was disabled. Changing it to readonly in template fixed this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My control called variableAmount was disabled. Changing it to readonly in template fixed this bug.

Answer (score 0):

You probably the other controls disabled, which disables their validations